# Spring MVC: how to implement DAO from custom interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dao, implements

My purpose is to implement custom DAO interface and that's what I do, but it seems does not work.

My interface is:

```
public interface AbstractDAO<T> {

    void add(T object);
    T load(Integer ID);
    List<T> list();
    void update(T object);
    void delete(Integer ID);
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
@Repository
public class AccountDAO implements AbstractDAO<Account> {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Account object) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

as I told, it doesn't work due Spring scanner cannot find the dao class.

How to let this work? Without `implements` it works fine.

**Spring scanner configuration:**

```
<bean ...>
   <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="tmp" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="services" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="entities" />

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <tx:annotation-driven />
   <task:annotation-driven />

   <import resource="spring-beans.xml"/>
</bean>
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [dao.AccountDAO] found for dependency: expected
at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
```

Comment: can you share your spring scanner configurations ?

Comment: also, what is the error you get ?\

Comment: It occurs when I try to use `AccountDAO` inside controllers. Controllers are inside `tmp` directory which is under scan as well.

Comment: looks like you are auto-wiring the  `AccountDao` 
try to auto-wire `AbstractDAO` with `qualifier`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using Spring Data?

Comment: @Udy, I'd tried what you suggested but still no effect. I'd renamed `AccountDAO` to `AccountDao` and the parent interface as well. Still the same.

Comment: @chrylis, no there's not. I just never heard about this

Comment: This has to do with Spring using JDK-based interface proxies by default, and the type of the bean thus being `AbstractDAO<Account>`, and not `AccountDAO`. You should autowire the interface, not the concrete implementation.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks it's clear now. So, there's no way to use such inheritance with Spring components?

Comment: Why would there be no way? You just need to program on interfaces, not on concrete classes. How is that not using inheritance? You can also ask spring to proxy target classes with CGLib. Check the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `DAO` implementation to:

```
@Repository("accountDAO")
public class AccountDAO implements AbstractDAO<Account> {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Account object) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and the usage of the `DAO` like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class Controller

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("accountDAO")
    private AbstractDAO accountDAO;

    .....
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly still the same. I think this issue rather about spring inheritance rules than about the scanner, since it works without inheritance

Comment: @Codemaster, im sorry but i had a mistake where the reference in the `Controller` was `AccountDAO` instead of `AbstractDAO`.
try now..

Comment: actually it didn't utill I refused from interfaces usage